# OWIN Authentication with Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I'm using owin authentication on an ASPNET MVC project. When using google I have the following problem:

1- The user signs in with the google account

2- The user signs out

3- The next time the user tries to sign in, the current google account is automatically used to sign in again without prompting the user is he wants to use another account.

Question: How can I, using the owin google authentication, prompt the user if he wants to use the current account or use a different one?

Thanks

Comment: How you manage your sign in process? Aren't you using two separate buttons and actions for normal login and Google login? If you haven't properly sign out during your sing off method call. There may be caching issue. Debug and check your status during 2nd time login?

Comment: Sorry, I saw now that I wasn't clear enough. On step 3, I'm talking about a google login again. Currently, I'm not supporting my own system accounts, only google and facebook. The problem is when the user tries to login again with google, the current google account is used instead of asking the user explicitly if he wants to use the current logged google account or if he wants to change to another. Maybe this is not possible? For instance, here at stackoverflow they indicate, when you logout, that you should also logout from your id provider. Maybe I have to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using external login provider (Google in your case) to sign in to your application, then your application will get authenticated by third party provider (Google in your case).

After successful registration asp.net identity framework store provider key return from third party provider in AspNetUserLogins table which will be used when sign in next time.

But the user sign out from your application does not means that the user sign out from Google. Because of that if you are using the same browser which is already authenticated for your Google account will allow you to login to your application using the already authentication Google account.

There is no simple out of the box option in Asp.Net identity framework to sign out from both external provider (Google) and your application when you are calling sign out in your application.

You have to call [Google API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/sign-out) to sign out from Google account when you are calling sign out in your application in order to achieve your requirement.

You can see this [work item](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/1942) to get more details on this.