# Authenticate ASP.NET MVC app with OWIN without login to gmail etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, google-authentication

I got ASP.NET MVC application which Authenticate users by Google Account via OWIN library.

The users are expected sometime login to the web app on host computer (customer's) computer, public computer to manage some data in the web app.

There is a login button which redirects you to Google login page, user enter username and password and is redirected back to this web app. Until now it is OK, this is how OWIN usually works.

There is a risk I concern that user forget to logout the app and someone will capture the data from the web app. This is a risk in any web app right, I have to accept it. But there is a additional risk that if user forgot to logout, someone will capture all emails from gmail, google documents and all related Google services.

**I would like to modify the Owin Authentication in way that after Owin redirects user to Google login page, Google will just pass the authorization to web app without login user to Gmail and all related Google services in web browser.**

Following code also login to Gmail as side effect of the web app authentication. I see that there is a lot of configuration option of OWIN. I believe it is achievable:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private double _expirationTimeCookies = 30; // minutes - sliding expiration

    public static ApplicationUserManager ApplicationUserManagerCreate(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
        var tokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(options.DataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));

        ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        }

        return ApplicationUserManager.Create(tokenProvider, manager);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {           
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManagerCreate);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_expirationTimeCookies),   

            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_expirationTimeCookies),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, Helpers.IdentityExtensions.OnlineSettingsForAccount(user.Id)))
            }
        });                       
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxx",
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
            {                    
                OnApplyRedirect = delegate(GoogleOAuth2ApplyRedirectContext context)
                {                     
                    string redirect = context.RedirectUri;
                    redirect += "&prompt=select_account";
                    context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
                }
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, to clarify: your app runs on a public computer, and you want to prevent that if a consumer forgets to sign out, the next user can open the previous user's GMail and other Google services?

Comment: And how will google verify that user without making him log into google services?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Evk I would expect that google will just verify the username and password and call the redirect url without saving authentication cookie for google.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522192/130387 - doesn't look like its possible out of the box.  You would need a) add a function to call the logout endpoint to Google on logout and b) have some ability to track logins, track if a login is expired, and POST a logout call to Google if expired but the user didnt click logout - but even then I'm not sure what all information you would need to send to Google to complete the logout (can you do this with simply the oAuth code received from login for instance).

Answer (score 7):

Google does not provide such option. When you redirect to google to obtain openid\oauth token, it will always ask user to log in to google first (if not logged in already) to verify users' identity, and only after that will issue a token for your application. In theory, google could provide an option to verify username and password and issue token without establishing session with google itself, but I see no reason why would they ever do that. Keeping user logged in as much as possible is beneficial to google, and also this would interfere with main goal of such authentication flow, that is - typing password as rare as possible.

So, after you got your token, user is also logged in to google services and you cannot change that. What you can do though, is log out target person of google immediately after obtaining token. For that, you can redirect user to the following url:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://yoursite.com;
```

This will log user off google services and then redirect him back to your site.

Note that:

1. While it works now, it is not documented anywhere (at least I'm not aware of that), so it might stop working some time in future.
2. Doing that might be **very** annoying to user. After each log in to your site, user will be logged off from google. I personally would never use a site doing such thing (after I would be able to figure out what happens at all that is, because it's not trivial).

So I'd suggest to not use this approach and instead instruct your users about dangers of such authentication on public computers (by introducing "public computer" checkbox on login form and showing information if it's clicked), or at the very least - don't do this always but only if user explicitly tells you that he is on public computer right now.